# Implementing N-tier structure in .net

Tags: .net, oop, n-tier-architecture

my requirement - suppose I have three classes namely Employee, Customer and Department. Employee contains attributes id, name, dept. Customer contains id and name. Department contains id and name. Now all three class have common functionality i.e. create, update and delete. I want to implement these functions using an interface. So can anyone sugest how I can perform these things in an n-tier architecture?

Comment: Seems more that you need an O/RM that separates your domain from the rest of your application. You could take a look at Entity Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

N-tier architecture splits an application into seperate tiers with a disctinct concern.

What you originally outline is about OO design, which is a bit different.

If you want to learn about implementing an OO design in an n-tier application, then [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321127420) would be a good start.